# Gradle on build copy generated binaries to some location

Tags: gradle

How to copy on build - generated binaries to some location?

I could imagine:

```
jar {
  doLast {
    copy./..???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should do the job:

```
jar {
   doLast {
      copy {
         from jar.outputs
         into 'destination_dir'
      }
   }
}
```